# Deducing rank from forall quantification

Tags: haskell

Given the code below (from [Yoneda Lemma explanation](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/11/yoneda-lemma.html)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

check1 :: a -> (forall b . (a -> b) -> b)
check1 a f = f a

uncheck1 :: (forall b . (a -> b) -> b) -> a
uncheck1 t = t id
```

`forall` quantification for `check1` seems to be `rank-1` as confirmed in `ghci`:

```
$ :t check1
check1 :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
$ :t uncheck1
uncheck1 :: (forall b. (a -> b) -> b) -> a
```

I can't figure out why `check1` has `rank-1` type signature, while `uncheck1` still maintains `rank-2` type signature. I read the type signature for `check1` as "For all types `b`, accept a function of type `a` to `b` where `a` is fixed, and return a value of type `b`". That led me to believe that the user is not allowed to select type `b` in advance (unlike type `a`), and hence, the type should be `rank-2`. There seem to be some nuances here that I am definitely missing when trying to learn whether an explicit `forall` signature should be read as rank-1 or higher rank.

**Update:** 
Though I have accepted the answer below, [this email explanation](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-May/043581.html) from Lennart Augustsson in terms of `capital lambda` is very clear and intuitive in my opinion - it cuts through the caller-callee confusion, and clearly shows how to do type-level lambda to interpret `forall`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it happens we can float at the `forall` in `check1` since it's on the right of that arrow.

```
 check1 :: a -> (forall b. (a -> b) -> b)
 check1 :: forall b. a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

An intuition for this, in `uncheck1`, who get's to choose what `b` is? Certain not the caller, since that function has to work for all `b`'s.

In `check1` the caller does get to choose `b`, since we have to return a function that works for all `b`. We're returning the function to them, so they can specialize it to whatever they choose. Since the caller gets to choose anyways, this is exactly equivalent to

```
check1 :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

The [HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types) page discusses this.

Comment: @rampion Bleh dumb mistake, I meant `uncheck1`. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: @jozefg, still not clear why caller gets to choose `b` in `check1`

Comment: @Sal You're returning the function to them, so they get to specialize it to whatever they choose.

Comment: @jozefg, this is important insight. You should add it to the answer.